# Generic start of a sentence with multiple choices

Tags: phrase-request

I am looking for a sentence start for a question about making a decision.

Questions with a single yes/no choice, and questions with a complete list of choices, can start with

- **Should I** quit my job? (yes/no)
- **Should I** eat pizza or burger? (list of options)

But to ask a question without giving the list of options, it seems that one needs to put the "question-word" (also known as w-word) at the beginning:

- **What** should I eat?
- **Where** should I go?

Is there a construct that allows to start such a question with a fixed set of words?

- **Lorem ipsum** where I go?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want this?  Why do you need the questions to start with the same phrase.  How should the reader distinguish between "What should I eat?" and "Where should I eat?"

Comment: For a website input mask I need to format the question into <SOME TEXT><user-entered question><QUESTIONMARK>, something like I WONDER how/if/... ?

Comment: Can the "some text" be the empty string?

Comment: James, no, unfortunately not. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Open questions in English are headed by the question pronoun: "what", "where" and so on, and you need to use a appropriate pronoun to the question. The question word has meaning beyond marking a question, there is a difference between

> What should I eat?

and

> Where should I eat?

In some contexts you might be able to get away with an imperative:

> Tell me your destination
>   Tell me your food choice.

It's clumsy but correct. Insted of "tell me" you could use "write down" or "indicate"

You can even just write the noun and allow the question to be implied.

> Name .................
>   Destination..............
>   Food choice.............